# Running multi-stacker docker built docker image fails – Nexts cannot find react module

Tags: docker, next.js, yarnpkg, preact, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm building a multi-stage docker image for a project that uses nextjs and preact within a lerna monorepo.

The multi-stage build succeeds, however, when I want to run the image, nextjs throws an error that 'react' cannot be found.

The Dockerfile for the multi-stage build:

```
FROM node:12 as builder

RUN curl -sfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/tj/node-prune.sh | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin

RUN npm -g config set user root && \
    npm install -g lerna

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

ARG TARGET_APP_FOLDER=apps/app-1

# Install dependencies
COPY yarn.lock ./
WORKDIR /app/${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}
RUN lerna bootstrap \
    -- --production

# Build
ARG PROJECT_ID
RUN test -n "$PROJECT_ID" || (echo "PROJECT_ID not set. Need to set PROJECT_ID to the GCP project ID you're deploying to" && false)

ENV PROJECT_ID=${PROJECT_ID}
RUN yarn run build:prod && \
    /usr/local/bin/node-prune

################################################

# Our final image
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN yarn global add next

ARG TARGET_APP_FOLDER=apps/app-1

WORKDIR /app

# copy from build image
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}/package.json ./package.json

ENV PORT=8080
CMD yarn run start -p ${PORT}
```

I verified in the final that the `react` module has been copied to the node_modules folder. The react module itself is just using an alias to use `preact/compat`.

When running everything in a single builder it works perfectly fine:

```
FROM node:12 as builder

RUN curl -sfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/tj/node-prune.sh | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin

RUN npm -g config set user root && \
    npm install -g lerna

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

ARG TARGET_APP_FOLDER=apps/app-1

# Install dependencies
COPY yarn.lock ./
WORKDIR /app/${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}
RUN lerna bootstrap \
    -- --production

# Build
ARG PROJECT_ID
RUN test -n "$PROJECT_ID" || (echo "PROJECT_ID not set. Need to set PROJECT_ID to the GCP project ID you're deploying to" && false)

ENV PROJECT_ID=${PROJECT_ID}
RUN yarn run build:prod && \
    /usr/local/bin/node-prune

# Start the server
ENV PORT=8080
CMD yarn run start -p ${PORT}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

This is the dockerfile I'm using right now in case anyone stumbles on the same issue:

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS base

# DEFAULT ARGS
ENV BUILD_FOLDER=/build
ENV TARGET_APP_FOLDER=/apps/my_app

# CHECK PROJECT ID IS SET
ARG PROJECT_ID
RUN test -n "$PROJECT_ID" || (echo "PROJECT_ID not set. Need to set PROJECT_ID to the GCP project ID you're deploying to" && false)
ENV PROJECT_ID=${PROJECT_ID}

###### BUILDER BASE PREPARING FILES ######

FROM base AS builder_base

WORKDIR /base

RUN apk update && \
    apk add curl bash && \
    apk --no-cache add g++ make libpng-dev && \
    curl -sfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/tj/node-prune.sh | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin

# COPY YARN LOCK
COPY yarn.lock ./

# Copy source
COPY . ./

# Remove unused source
RUN bin/delete-unused-apps.sh ${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}

###### BUILDER ######

FROM builder_base AS build
WORKDIR ${BUILD_FOLDER}
COPY --from=builder_base /base ./

ENV PATH=${BUILD_FOLDER}/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN yarn install --production

WORKDIR ${BUILD_FOLDER}/${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}

RUN yarn build:prod && \
    /usr/local/bin/node-prune


###### RUNNER ######

FROM base AS runner
ARG PROJECT_ID
ENV PROJECT_ID=${PROJECT_ID}
ENV PATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build ${BUILD_FOLDER}/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build ${BUILD_FOLDER}${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build ${BUILD_FOLDER}${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}/public ./public
COPY --from=build ${BUILD_FOLDER}${TARGET_APP_FOLDER}/package*.json ./

# Start the server
ENV PORT=8080
CMD yarn run start -p ${PORT}
```